# Trying to figure out how to get my MongoDB Database to bring up items that belong to a certain user (by ID)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get my Mongo Database to extract out the items (Portfolio pics) that a user has submitted, but when I previewed the items extracted via the Console logs,it displayed all of the portfolio pieces for everyone instead of just that specific user.

Here are the codes that I typed in Javascript to attempt to get it to work so far:

On the back end side:

```
(For the routes)--------------------------------------
//GET - get all portfolio pieces for a certain user ----------------------
router.get('/:id', Utils.authenticateToken, (req, res) => {
  Portfolio.findById({user: req.body._id}).populate('user', '_id firstName lastName displayName')
  console.log({user: req.body._id})
  .then(userPortfolio => {
    if(userPortfolio == null){
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: "No portfolio pieces found"
      })
    }
    res.json(userPortfolio)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Problem getting portfolio pieces"
    })
  })  
})  

For the Portfolio Model (Schema) file:
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const Utils = require('./../utils')

// schema
const portfolioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true

  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    required: true    
  },
  tag: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
  },
  link: {
    type: String,
  }
  
}, { timestamps: true, collection: 'portfolioPs' })


// model
const portfolioModel = mongoose.model('Portfolio', portfolioSchema)

// export
module.exports = portfolioModel
```

And for the front end side:

```
init(){
    console.log('ProfileView.init')
    document.title = 'Profile' 
    this.userPortfolio = null    
    this.render()    
    Utils.pageIntroAnim()
    this.getUserPortfolio()
  }

  async getUserPortfolio(){
    try{
      this.userPortfolio = await PortfolioAPI.getUserPortfolio(Auth.currentUser._id)
      console.log(this.userPortfolio)
      this.render()
    }catch(err){
      Toast.show(err, 'error')
    }
  }
```

Do let me know if you need any further code to help me resolve this issue mates! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that your frontend call `await PortfolioAPI.getUserPortfolio` is really calling `router.get('/:id'...`? Because you are using `.findById(..)` in there, which should return **one** document only: [mongoose findById](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)

Answer (score 0):

use `Portfolio.find({user: req.body._id})` to get list of of all items that a user has submitted. It will return an array result

P.S:
`Portfolio.findById(someId)` is used to fetch only 1 specific document where result is an object by matching its `_id` field

Comment: I see. Alrighty. I'll give it a try then!

Comment: {"_id":{"$oid":"607c2198dea5219e13100e25"},
"name":"Natalie Portman",
"description":"When you're feeling like a black swan.",
"price":30,
"user":{"$oid":"60b38efdbcd20f2148c408d6"},
"image":"natalie-portman.jpg","tag":"photography"}

I wanted to grab user: ObjectID and have all the portfolio items belonging to a certain user instead of all the portfolio items  by every user in the database...

Strangely, it still grabbed all of them.

Comment: check `req.body._id`, it might be `None` and thus the query is not working properly.
If this is not the case, do paste the query you are writing so I have clearer idea.